# How Much Information Do Canadian and USA Immigration Share

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

It’s common knowledge that USA and Canadian immigration are probably the most tightly coupled immigration collaboration in the world.

How much do they really share on applicants, immigrants, border crossers?

PS: The question is not about whether they share information, that’s already settled and might even already have an answer here.

Comment: Why do you think they would make that public?

Comment: I doubt they’re as tightly coupled as those of the Schengen countries, or the UK and Ireland, or other groups of countries that have open and unpoliced borders between themselves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently they share almost everything:

[image]

Source: [Directives for Sharing Information Pursuant to the 2003 Canada-U.S. Statement of Mutual Understanding on Information Sharing](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/resources/manuals/in/in02-eng.pdf) (Appendix B, page 28).

Comment: A better question would have been how they share information. In the case of USA-Canada, the share based on on biographic AND biometric data. You should assume each country has access to at least all electronically stored immigration and criminal data.

Comment: Note that the document itself says that this is information that "may" be shared. It doesn't say that all of this information is *always* shared about every person, or is even available for all people. Consider "26. Education". Maybe they have access to your high school diploma and any university degrees you have earned, but how likely are they to specifically know or share that you have been checking out Teach Yourself Gardening books from your local library, or that your grandmother has been teaching you to conjugate Polish verbs?