# Will there be an impact of US visit Visa rejection to obtain Canada express entry visa?

Tags: usa, canada

I am planning to migrate to Canada through express entry program. Last year I applied US visit visa and it got rejected and I do not know the exact reason for the rejection. Will there be an impact of this rejection for Canadian visa?

Comment: It may have an effect, as [Canada and the US do share immigration information](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124377/); how much impact would be difficult to predict.

Comment: Also, your US application was for a visit; you're now applying to immigrate to Canada, quite different, a much more rigorous process and in which the US visa refusal might be less of an issue, or none at all.

Comment: It depends on the reason. If for example you were denied because of a serious criminal background, you can bet Canada will deny your long term visa application.