# If I have a previous visa refusal from Country A, will it impact on my application to Country B too?

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, study

So I have already applied for Canadian Study Permit (SDS). Before this I had a visa approved for US (tourist) in 2018 and for China (business) in 2017.

The main problem came when I had been refused a visa for Germany in 2017 april. Before that I have been approved a tourist visa for Italy.

So now comes the question although I have been approved with visas after rejection, what I want to know is Can it impact my Canadian Visa application. Since my purpose of travel for the German visa was study and so is for the Canadian visa. Although I have attached a letter of explanation for the same and didn't lie on my application.

But for both previous, US and China, I lied to the question where it asks for 'If you have been refused entry to a country.....'.

Also if somebody can let me know, that does having US visa gains you a preference or something when applying for other countries?

Comment: Related question on sharing of information between USA and Canada https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124377/how-much-information-do-canadian-and-usa-immigration-share

Comment: So, you told the Americans you hadn't been refused before, and you're now telling the Canadians that you have. Given that the two countries share a great deal of immigration data it's possible that the Canadians already know about your previous false declaration. If they manage to link that with your current true declaration the discrepancy will pretty much guarantee you a refusal.

Comment: @Redd Herring the Canadians won't know about his USA immigration history unless he is is refused an immigration benefit by USA. Then they will.

Answer (score 3):

By lying to immigration, you have made your travel life much more complicated and much riskier. The reasons are two: first, it's difficult to keep your stories straight if you say one thing to one person while saying another thing to other people (and this gets progressively harder the more people and agencies are involved), and second, some immigration agencies share information. Consequently, the only advice you'll hear here is "Tell the truth."

If you'd been honest throughout, then having obtained a US visa in 2018 would bolster your current Canadian application, as the grant of a visa shows that the US authorities found your application trustworthy.

You said you didn't lie on the Canada application, so you will have disclosed in that application the rejection from Germany. But you did lie in the US application for the 2018 visa, and denied receiving the German rejection. Thus, the content of your US visa application is different from the content of your current Canada application.

The US and Canada share a great deal of intelligence information under the *[Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes)* agreement. No one knows specifically what information, but the two countries clearly have the authority to share immigration information (see the discussion [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124377/how-much-information-do-canadian-and-usa-immigration-share)), and anecdotal evidence from the US/Canada border suggests that immigration information is indeed part of the shared data stream. If information is shared (a perfectly reasonable possibility), and if the information is cross-checked as a matter of course (another perfectly reasonable possibility), then the Canadian visa authorities will see that you *answered the visa rejection question differently on the US application than you did on the current Canadian application*.

It's even possible that information about the German visa rejection is directly shared with Canada or the US, which would make the discovery even more certain.

Saying different things at different times to different recipients will be seen as misrepresentation; more brutally: they'll conclude you must have lied at least once. Discovering your misrepresentation is likely to result in the denial of your application to Canada. It will also do no good whatsoever for any future application for a visa to enter the US.

I don't know what might be done here, if anything. At this point, I'd stop asking questions of random strangers on the internet, and find an immigration attorney in Canada. You don't have to be physically in Canada to hire counsel there, and right now you want someone who knows the Canadian immigration system. If you want to apply to the US in the future, I think you'll then need a US immigration attorney.

Comment: The USA application form does not ask about refusal of entry to other countries. Starting in a couple of days it will ask about "removals and deportations" but not about refusals on entry. Edit: Neither does China (http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/fd/W020130830801798289342.pdf)

Comment: Interesting. The OP said they lied to visa authorities. Admitting a lie is a declaration against interest, which admissions are often or usually deemed presumptively true. The info may have been offered in an attached explanation, or in the oral interview conducted by consular staff. Because the OP was clear that they offered conflicting responses to different recipients, however, the gist of the Answer remains correct.